# Convert String in to MAC address

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, esp32

Inside the file in SPIFFS, I'm saving information about the mac address in the form "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX".
When I read the file, I need to switch it from STRING to a array of hexadecimal values.

```
uint8_t* str2mac(char* mac){
  uint8_t bytes[6];
  int values[6];
  int i;
  if( 6 == sscanf( mac, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x%*c",&values[0], &values[1], &values[2],&values[3], &values[4], &values[5] ) ){
      /* convert to uint8_t */
      for( i = 0; i < 6; ++i )bytes[i] = (uint8_t) values[i];
  }else{
      /* invalid mac */
  } 
  return bytes;
}

wifi_set_macaddr(STATION_IF, str2mac((char*)readFileSPIFFS("/mac.txt").c_str()));
```

But I'm wrong in the code somewhere

When i put `AA:00:00:00:00:01` in file, my ESP8266 set `29:D5:23:40:00:00`

I need help, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a "local" variable, i.e. one which's lifetime ends when the function is finished. Using such a pointer then is UB, which may be, for example, the behaviour you are seeing.

To overcome this, you could pass the array as parameter; then the caller is responsible for memory management.
BTW: you could use format `%hhx` to read in directly into an 8 bit unsigned data type:

```
int str2mac(const char* mac, uint8_t* values){
    if( 6 == sscanf( mac, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",&values[0], &values[1], &values[2],&values[3], &values[4], &values[5] ) ){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {

    uint8_t values[6] = { 0 };
    int success = str2mac("AA:00:00:00:00:01", values);
    if (success) {
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
            printf("%02X:",values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I always get 0 for the variable "success"

Comment: can you `printf("'%s'",mac)` inside `str2mac`?

Comment: printf("'%s'",mac) does not return anything

Comment: then it is clear that the function returns `0`. Please check the input, probably by using a debugger.

Comment: Sorry, this is a microcontroller problem https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=437982.0  Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to be compatible with `wifi_set_macaddr` (I looked up API documentation). It expects a `uint8` pointer to mac address, which means the way you wrote it is not going to work (returning pointer to local variable etc). Here is an example which you should be able to adapt to your purpouse:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// mock up/print result
bool wifi_set_macaddr(uint8_t index, uint8_t *mac) 
{
    std::cout << "index: " << (int)index << " mac: "; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        std::cout << std::hex << (int)mac[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return true;
}


// test file
void writeTestFile()
{   
    std::ofstream ofs("mac.txt");
    if (!(ofs << "AA:00:00:00:00:01" << std::endl))
    {
        std::cout << "File error" << std::endl;
    }
    ofs.close();
}

int main() 
{
    writeTestFile();

    uint8_t mac[6];
    int i = 0, x;

    std::ifstream ifs("mac.txt");
    for (; i < 6 && ifs >> std::hex >> x; ++i)
    {
        mac[i] = static_cast<uint8_t>(x);
        ifs.ignore();
    }

    if (i < 6)
    {
        std::cout << "File error or invalid MAC address" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    wifi_set_macaddr(0x00, mac);

    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d387c628e590a467